# Can't deserialize json response from Flurry API

Tags: java, json, spring, flurry

I am trying to read in some stats using Flurry's REST API in to my Spring application. However my objects are coming back with null values for all fields. I think this is because the JSON response prepends @ symbols to the non-array fields in the response. The responses I'm getting look like this:

```
{
  "@endDate": "2015-06-16",
  "@metric": "PageViews",
  "@startDate": "2015-06-16",
  "@generatedDate": "6/16/15 5:06 PM",
  "@version": "1.0",
  "day": [
          {
            "@date": "2015-06-16",
            "@value": "0"
          }
         ]
}
```

The code I'm using to make the request looks like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
FlurryAppMetric appMetric = restTemplate.getForObject(url, FlurryAppMetric.class);
return appMetric;
```

Where FlurryAppMetric is the following (getters & setters omitted):

```
public class FlurryAppMetric {
    private String metric;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private String generatedDate;
    private String version;
    private ArrayList<FlurryMetric> day;
}

public class FlurryMetric {
    private String date;
    private String value;
}
```

One possible solution is to parse it all in as a map, but I'd like to take advantage of the mapper they expose if at all possible.

If there's some way to just make a GET request and receive the body as a string I would be able to clean the response and try passing it in to a mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to parse it with GSON, using the `@SerializedName` annotation, like this :

```
public class FlurryAppMetric {
    @SerializedName("@metric");
    private String metric;

    @SerializedName("@startDate");
    private String startDate;

    @SerializedName("@endDate");
    private String endDate;

    @SerializedName("@generatedDate");
    private String generatedDate;

    @SerializedName("@versionDate");
    private String version;

    @SerializedName("day");
    private ArrayList<FlurryMetric> day;
}

public class FlurryMetric {
    @SerializedName("@date");
    private String date;

    @SerializedName("@value");
    private String value;
}
```

Then use Gson like this :

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.fromJson(<string json source>, FlurryApiMetric.class);
```

Comment: That's good to know, that way I wouldn't need to manipulate the JSON string. I'm still not sure what class(es) I should use to make a GET request in Spring to get the response body as a string.

Comment: If Flurry uses GSON, you can just add the annotation to the model and leave the FlurryAppMetric implementation as-is :D

Answer (score 1):

reidzeibel got me on the right track. I am using the Jackson FasterXML parser because that is what org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate uses behind the scenes. Similar to the GSON library's **@SerializedName**, the Jackson library provides an **@JsonProperty** member property. My resulting model classes look like this:

```
public class FlurryAppMetric {
    @JsonProperty("@metric")
    private String metric;

    @JsonProperty("@startDate")
    private String startDate;

    @JsonProperty("@endDate")
    private String endDate;

    @JsonProperty("@generatedDate")
    private String generatedDate;

    @JsonProperty("@version")
    private String version;

    private ArrayList<FlurryMetric> day;
}

public class FlurryMetric {
    @JsonProperty("@date")
    private String date;

    @JsonProperty("@value")
    private String value;
}
```

Comment: Glad it works! actually I also uses Jackson regularly, was answering on GSON because retrofit uses it :D

Comment: Right, I'm only using Jackson because that REST client class provided by Spring uses it under the covers. :D